# Trouble publishing WASM Uno Solution to App Service Azure and a local Publish folder (Error CS2012)

Tags: uno-platform

When I try to publish my Uno Platform WASM solution from within Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.0 either to an App Service in Azure or to a local publish folder I get the following error.

CSC(0,0): Error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users...\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\FileName.Wasm.dll' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users...\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\FileName.Wasm.dll' because it is being used by another process.'

I have had this problem before and then I have moved the entire solution to another folder (with shorter filepath) and been able to publish from there. This time that doesn't work either.

I have tried rebooting and only starting Visual Studio and trying to publish directly, cleaning the solution and adding the following in the Wasm.csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WasmShellEnableLongPathSupport>false</WasmShellEnableLongPathSupport>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

But still no go.
I am using Uno... v3.5.1 and Uno.Wasm... v1.3.6

An update: I noticed that it starts to run Roslyn\csc.exe after the publish has started. Could this explain it?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Client.Wasm, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Client.Wasm -> C:\...\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Client.Wasm.dll
1>Done building project "Client.Wasm.csproj".
2>------ Publish started: Project: Client.Wasm, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:NU1701,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETSTANDARD;NETSTANDARD2_0;UNO_REFERENCE_API;HAS_UNO_WASM;__WASM__;UNO_REFERENCE_API;HAS_UNO_WASM;__WASM__;HAS_UNO;UNO_HAS_FRAMEWORKELEMENT_MEASUREOVERRIDE;UNO_HAS_NO_IDEPENDENCYOBJECT;UNO_REFERENCE_API /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\commonservicelocator\2.0.5\lib\netstandard2.0\CommonServiceLocator.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.console\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.filter\1.1.1\lib\netstandard1.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.AppContext.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.1\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Collections.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.collections.immutable\1.3.1\lib\netstandard1.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Collections.Specialized.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Console.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Core.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Data.Common.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Globalization.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.Compression.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.FileSystem.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.Pipes.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Linq.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Linq.Parallel.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.memory\4.5.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Http.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.NameResolution.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Ping.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Security.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.Sockets.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Net.WebSockets.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Numerics.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.numerics.vectors\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Reflection.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.emit.ilgeneration\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.emit.lightweight\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Resources.Reader.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Resources.Writer.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.3\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Claims.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Security.SecureString.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.Thread.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Transactions.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.ValueTuple.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Web.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Windows.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.Serialization.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.XPath.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.Core.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.diagnostics.eventing\1.0.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.Diagnostics.Eventing.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.Foundation.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.foundation.runtime.webassembly\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.Foundation.Runtime.WebAssembly.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.UI.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.UI.FluentTheme.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui.runtime.webassembly\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.UI.Runtime.WebAssembly.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.UI.Toolkit.dll /reference:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Uno.Xaml.dll /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\netstandard2.0\Client.Wasm.dll /resource:WasmCSS\Fonts.css,Client.Wasm.WasmCSS.Fonts.css /resource:WasmScripts\AppManifest.js,Client.Wasm.WasmScripts.AppManifest.js /resource:LinkerConfig.xml,Client.Wasm.xml /resource:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Wasm\obj\Release\netstandard2.0\g\ResourcesGenerator\Strings\en\Resources.resw\Resources.upri,Strings.en.Resources.resw.Resources.upri /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:7.3 /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\Uno.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CommonServiceLocator.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Uno.Core.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Uno.Xaml.dll /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\MainPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\BaseData.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\BlankPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\CustomerPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\HomePage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\InspectionPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\InspectionTemplatePage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\MachinesPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\CommentsPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\InspectionSummariesPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\StatusPage.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\App.xaml /additionalfile:C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Strings\en\Resources.resw /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\Uno.Analyzers.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\CommonServiceLocator.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Mono.Cecil.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Uno.Core.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Uno.UI.SourceGenerators.dll /additionalfile:C:\Users\nivu\.nuget\packages\uno.ui\3.5.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Uno.Xaml.dll Program.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\App.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\Authenticator.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\DsipachedBindableBase.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\IdHolders\SavedTemplateIds.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\IdHolders\StaticTypes.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\IdHolders\UriItem.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\RelayCommand.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\RESTMessage.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Helpers\UnoHttpClientHandler.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\MainPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Addresses.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\AddressTypes.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\AllTypes.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\CheckTypes.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\ClientSettings.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Comments.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\CommentsForCreation.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\ContactForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\ContactForUpdateDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Contacts.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Customers.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\GUIBase.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\IInspection.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionCommentsDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionComponentDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionItemDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionItemsForUpdateDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionResourceDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionSegmentDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionTableRowDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionTemplateDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionTemplateForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\InspectionTemplates.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Machines.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\MachinesForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\MachineTypes.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Parts.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\PredefinedSummary.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\TemplateComponents.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\TemplateItemComments.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\TemplateItems.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\Templates.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\DataModels\TemplateSegments.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\ForCreation\ClientSettingsForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\ForCreation\CloneForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\ForCreation\InspectionItemCommentsForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\ForCreation\PredifinedSummaryForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Models\ForCreation\TemplateItemCommentsForCreationDto.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\BaseData.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\BlankPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\CustomerPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\HomePage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\InspectionPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\InspectionTemplatePage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\MachinesPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\CommentsPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\InspectionSummariesPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\Pages\SettingsPages\StatusPage.xaml.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\ValueConverters\AddressTypeToString.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\ValueConverters\BoolToInvertedBool.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\ValueConverters\BoolTrueToColor.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\ValueConverters\CheckTypeIdToString.cs C:\source\Admin\Client\Client\Client.Shared\ValueConverters\IntegerToString.cs ---
```

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? Did you resolve the problem?